# ping command not working in Cygwin

Tags: windows, shell, ssh, cygwin, openssh

I am trying to use the terminal on a Windows machine and so I have installed Cygwin.

When I try to test if Cygwin works using ping, it gives me an error.

```
$ ping google.com
-bash: ping: command not found
```

I expected a result like the one below:

```
$ ping google.com
Pinging google.com [74.125.227.105] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 74.125.227.105: bytes=32 time=65ms TTL=51
```

Could someone help me with this? Is there something wrong with the installation of cygwin.

Comment: Have you installed inetutils? I see a workaround also is to do: `ln -s /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/ping/exe ping.exe` and then use it like `./ping.exe google.com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run the cygwin setup `setup.exe` and check the inetutils. If you have a 64-bit version of Cygwin please check this:

https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2013-10/msg00336.html

Answer (score 0):

Create System variable as below :-

Variable Name :- path
Variable Value :- C:\Windows\System32

Restart your Cygwin terminal and check it will work